# Add new row after 4th album PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach, row

so I am trying to add a new row after every 4th gallery and continue on until I am out of galleries to add. So if there is 17 galleries there will be 4 rows of 4 galleries and 1 row of the remaining gallery. here is an example of how it looks: http://www.csulb.edu/centers/latinohealth/media/galleries/

here is my code:

```
<?php $this->start_element('nextgen_gallery.gallery_container', 'container', $displayed_gallery); ?>

<div class="row-fluid secondone">
<div class="ngg-albumoverview span12">
<div class="row-fluid"> 
<?php $count = 0;?>
<?php foreach ($galleries as $gallery) {
    $count++;
    ?>


    <div class="ngg-album span3">
        <div class="ngg-albumtitle">
            <a href="<?php echo nextgen_esc_url($gallery->pagelink); ?>"><?php echo_safe_html($gallery->title); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ngg-albumcontent">
            <div class="ngg-thumbnail">
                <a class="gallery_link" href="<?php echo nextgen_esc_url($gallery->pagelink); ?>"><img class="Thumb" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($gallery->title); ?>" src="<?php echo nextgen_esc_url($gallery->previewurl); ?>"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="ngg-description">
                <p><?php echo_safe_html($gallery->galdesc); ?></p>
                <?php if (isset($gallery->counter) && $gallery->counter > 0) { ?>
                    <p><strong><?php echo $gallery->counter; ?></strong>&nbsp;<?php _e('Photos', 'nggallery'); ?></p>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if ($count % 4 == 0 ) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
<?php  } ?>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php $this->end_element(); ?>
```

Comment: this looks right, that site is the output of this code?

Comment: @hyperdrive Yes it is. I have no idea why its outputting that way

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek the output is right here: http://www.csulb.edu/centers/latinohealth/media/galleries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

the row:
`<?php if ($count % 4 == 0 ) ?>`

should be:
`<?php if ($count % 4 == 0 ) { ?>`

Comment: I will try this when I get back to work! I will keep you updated! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I tired it and it gives me a syntax error on line 35 which is: <?php $this->end_element(); ?>

Comment: I messed with the hierarchy of braces. I thought that the last closing brace was for the "if" statement but it concern the "foreach" loop. I add told to you to add an open brace, but then it should also be closed.

you need to add another "<?php  } ?>" to close the if statement, immediately before the one you already have in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do what you want with css styles, not with the php.
Create a container block with fixed width that can contain exacly 4 galleries and use the [float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) property on the boxes of the galleries.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap CSS so it doesnt really float correctly